# How to capture image when Face detect in centre with ARKit in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, arkit

I have used ARKit with ARFaceTrackingConfiguration to detect face using below code

```
        let configuration = ARFaceTrackingConfiguration()
        configuration.isLightEstimationEnabled = true
        sceneView.delegate = self
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        sceneView.session.run(configuration, options: [.resetTracking, .removeExistingAnchors])
```

For display line on face used below code

```
func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, nodeFor anchor: ARAnchor) -> SCNNode? {
            let faceMesh = ARSCNFaceGeometry(device: sceneView.device!)
            let node = SCNNode(geometry: faceMesh)
            node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.fillMode = .lines
            return node
        }
```

Issue: How to detect that face bound in CGRect frame because I want to capture an image if the face in the center of the screen.